# How to concate string using strcat()

Tags: c

This code want to concate the string but it do not show the output

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
main( ) 
    {  
    char *str1 = "United" ;  
    char *str2 = "Front" ;  
    char *str3 ;  
    str3 = strcat ( str1, str2 ) ;  
    printf ( "\n%s", *str3 ) ; 
    }
```

Comment: Turn on warnings for your compiler and it'll tell you what's wrong.

Comment: The first argument is the destination and therefore needs to be large enough to hold the concatenated result. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/

Comment: `strcat ( str1, str2 );` attempts to modify a *String Literal* invoking *Undefined Behavior*.

Comment: That is a weirdly exact duplicate. Is this from a coding test or something?

Answer (score 1):

I will list out the flaws in the code.

1. "United" and "Front" are string constants, meaning they cannot be modified.
2. strcat adds the second string to the first, as the first input is a constant string the operation is not possible.
3. printf just need the 'str3'.

There are 2 ways to correct the code, a) get the str1 through scanf b) get str1 by strcpy

I have provided the second solution, also str1 & str3 will both have the final answer.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
main( )
{
        char *str1=malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
        char *str2 = "Front" ;
        char *str3 ;
        if(str1){
                strcpy(str1,"United");
                str3 = strcat ( str1, str2 ) ;
                printf ( "%s\n", str3 ) ;
                free(str1);
        }
        else{
                printf("malloc failure!\n");
        }
}
```

With reference to the comments I have added a version without dynamic memory allocation:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main( )
{
        char str1[20];
        char *str2 = "Front" ;
        char *str3 ;
        strcpy(str1,"United");
        str3 = strcat ( str1, str2 ) ;
        printf ( "%s\n", str3 ) ;
}
```

Comment: `strcpy(str1,"United");`..uh oh!!

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Trying to use unitialized pointer as destination.

Comment: Sorry, have corrected it!

Comment: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917)

Comment: There is no success check for malloc return value

Comment: Finally, why do you even need to use dynamic allocation, when the size is compile time constant?

Comment: I didn't understand the last part. Can you provide a link?

Comment: It means: Why don't you simply use `char str1[20];` instead of dynamic memory? The size is small enough to fit on stack and it is known during compilation. No need for dynamic memory allocation overhead.